# Handle Input type number Increase-Decrease handle in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having a CartContext where I have INCREASE(by 1), DECREASE(by 1) or REMOVE functionalites.
I am also having an InputField Number and I wish to have to create a functionality to increase when upper arrow is clicked and decrease when lower arrow is clicked.
This is my current implementation:

```
<Col className="col-2">
    <input defaultValue={product.quantity} type="number" min="1" max="10" onChange={handleChange}/>
</Col>

const handleChange = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;    
};
```

I can use the Context values such as: `increase(product)` or `decrease(product)` but I am not sure how can I trigger these function calls for increase or decrease of input type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `useRef` here to preserve the value . Since you need the value to decide which function to call having the value maintained in the state is not needed here because updating the state might trigger a re-render.

```
const numberRef = useRef(product.quantity); // product.quantity

const handleChange = (e) => {
      if(e.target.value > numberRef.current){
        console.log('call increase function')
      } else {
        console.log('call decrease function')
      }
      numberRef.current = e.target.value
  }
```

We initialize the `useRef` with the `product.quantity` . Now the `numberRef` will be an object with the key `current` . It will be like this

```
{
  current: product.quantity
}
```

Now everytime when you update the value of the number input we compare it with the value in current if it is greater than the current we call the increase function and if it is less then we call the decrease function .

Now we set the `event.target.value` to `numberRef.current` .

Comment: I cannot follow this approach as there are a lot of products, product is a single item of list of ProductList.

Comment: In that case can you share more code . Its difficult to help with what you have shared.

Comment: share the complete code of the component which has `handleChange` this function .